# Extract final frame from a video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I know how to extract the first frame by using

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i input.mp4 -vframes 1 -q:v 31 output.png`

Here, the option `-ss` requires to know the exact time of the frame to extract.

I would like to have the final frame of any .mp4 without knowing the exact final time of the video.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i file -vsync 0 -q:v 31 -update true out.jpg
```

`-sseof` seeks from the end - I've used a value of 3, to account for files with longer audio streams. `-update` is an image2 muxer option which tells ffmpeg to overwrite the output file. So the last time the output will be overwritten is when the last frame is processed.

Comment: This works. Although it can be a bit slow since it needs to process the entire video...

Comment: No, it does not process the entire video, as long as your input is MP4/MKV stored on a local disk.

Comment: But I understand `-update` needs to pass every frame of the video, that's why you need to use `-vsync 0`. Sorry if I am using the word *process* wrong.

Comment: -update will write every frame it receives. `-sseof -3`  means it will only receive frames from the last 3 seconds of the video.

Comment: Have you tried to use different values for "-sseof -X" using 1, 3, 5 for X?
This leads to different pictures! Althought the last pic should be the same for each of the values, right?
Can anyone explain that?
Thx!

Comment: You added `-vframes 1` in your attempt, which is not present in my answer.